# Reinvoice every 12 months

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to create an invoice to auto populate. Have done this in VBA previously, but now the sheet is going on the cloud, and being used by Excel online so, VBA is out, unfortunately!

Trying to make a membership fee reappear every 12 months based on their start date!

I was trying around with EDATE, and got it to work on my test subject, but then realized it wouldn't work as I'm only going off the first 12 months!

Need a fresh set of eyes to give me ideas, or walk me through a simple solution (if possible)

Currently have the following, which works for the first year, then it won't!

```
Cell X7 = =EDATE(TODAY(),3) <----- Creates the cut off for invoicing if Membership due before then.
Cell V12 = =VLOOKUP(O12,'Youth Details'!$A$4:$H$95,8,0) <---- Returns their start date. i.e 19-Nov-2020
Cell W12 = =IF(AND(V12>TODAY(),V12<X7),"True", "False") <---- Returns if they have been with us for 9 months to 12 months and needs to be invoiced!
```

That works, for their first year, then the following year it won't invoice them as they've been there for 24 months.

I was thinking about expanding my VLOOKUP in cell V12, that if there membership was over 12 months ago, to add 12 to it, but got confused!

Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: Ah, my confusion, It uses Excel online. Not Google Sheet! Let me re-edit! Apologies

Comment: I'd probably go for: Calculate how many whole months have they been with us. Calculate `12 * the number of fees they have already paid`. Reach a conclusion as to whether they need to pay again.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it might be

1. Figure the number of months they've been a member, like say 34.
2. Use the `MOD()` modulus function with a divisor of 12 (months). This will discard the number of whole 12-month-periods (years) they've been a member and leave you with just the number of months since their last anniversary. So for 34, it'd give "10" months since their 2-year anniversary.
3. If the answer from #2 says they're getting close to renewal, like they're 9+ months in to their current membership year, invoice them.

```
Cell V12: =VLOOKUP(O12,'Youth Details'!$A$4:$H$95,8,0) <---- Returns their start date, like 1-Jan-2019
Cell V13: =DATEDIF(V12, TODAY(), "M") <---- Total # of months they've been a member, like 34
Cell W12: =IF(MOD(V13, 12) >= 9, "True", "False") <---- Returns if it's been 9+ months since their last anniversary and they need to be invoiced!
```

Of course, if you allow people to prepay, then like AakashM points out it's worth making sure you're not invoicing them for something they've already paid.